Pulling data but placing it with 17 blank rows between
My apologies if this is a silly question but I have scoured and the 2 answers I did ifnd didn't work.
I have 1 list of 200 names.
I have a payroll sheet that skips 17 lines between personnel.
How can I pull the names from that list and have it enter them into column B but skipping 17 lines?
The 2 files are on the same sheet with Sheet1 housing the list of names and Sheet2 housing the payroll data where the skips need to occur.
Thank you for your wisdom: Jo
I have tried several Offset formulas, adding a number to =B2, heck I even tried AI but the formulas it wrote were all jacked up.  What I need is:

Sheet1 B1 to go into Sheet2 B2,
Sheet1 B2 to go into Sheet2 B19,
Sheet1 B3 to go into Sheet2 B36,
ETC Ad nuaseum.


is there other data in the cell between?  Do you want a formula you drag down that returns empty in those cells?

Put this in B2 and drag it down:
=IF(MOD(ROW($ZZ1)-1,17)=0,INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,INT((ROW($ZZ1)-1)/17)+1,"")


If you have Excel Microsoft 365, you could enter the following as the first entry for payroll:

EXPAND to expand each name row with 17 blank cells in columns
TOCOL to convert this 200 rows x (names + 17 blank columns) to a single column, resulting in 17 blank rows in between the names

=LET(names,Sheet1!A1:A200, TOCOL(EXPAND(names, , 17 + 1, "")))



Please let me know if you don't have TOCOL etc. in your Excel version. I do have an alternate solution that would work.
